# How to handle authentication dialog while accessing the webpage from Excel macro

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to access one webpage and retrieve required data to Excel. Am using excel macro for this cause. The webpage that I am accessing is asking for username and password in the form of browser dialog like below:

[image: browser authentication dialog]

This is not a html page so am not able to locate the username and password texts and provide values.

I tried to give value directly using sendKeys

```
IE.Navigate Cells(rowNum, 3)   
SendKeys "admin"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "admin"
SendKeys "{Enter}
```

It is working fine if the dialog appears. But my webpage will ask for credentials only at the first instance. Rest of the time, the webpage is getting opened automatically without credentials. Now, I am in need of any way to check if this dialog box is visible. Could anyone help me in resolving this?

I tried with AppActivate

```
AppActivate(iexplore)
```

but this doesn't seem to be working.